# How to install Debian from an .iso on the filesystem?

Tags: boot

I am running Ubuntu and I want to be able to boot into Debian Wheezy .iso which I just downloaded, how can I set this up? I don't want to use an external device like a usb or cd/dvd

Answer (score 2):

You may try to *install* Debian through a VM (Virtual Machine) which would use your ISO in the virtual CD drive and using the destination partition as its storage. Virtualbox may work.

If you just need to *boot on a Live-CD*, don't even bother with the storage part.

Otherwise, if you have an available partition, you may even try using as if it was a USB key to boot on it:

```
dd if=your.iso of=/dev/sdaX bs=1M
```

Then, running `update-grub` may update the GRUB boot menu so that you can choose your ISO to boot on when you'll restart your computer. Otherwise, you can try to [chainload it](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Chain_002dloading) from the grub configuration file.

Comment: that sounds reasonable. however, when i do that, i get .. debian-live-7.2-amd64-gnome-desktop.iso:no such file or directory

Comment: @user_of_ubuntu_linux Are you in the directory where this iso file is stored?

Comment: yeah .. i also entered the full path name and still get this error even when i am root

Comment: sorry that was a stupid mistake .. i had to cd once .. i did that .. dd worked fine .. copied the iso on to /dev/sda5 .. however update-grub makes no mention of any new kernel images